# Tooltip for h:message is conflicting with the tooltip of the inputfield

Tags: jsf, richfaces, tooltip, message, render

For my inputfields i have a richface tooltip. This works fine. When i put invalid input in the field it goes all wrong.

To customize the h:message tooltip if have added there also a richface tooltip.
According to the following solution: [community.jboss.org](https://community.jboss.org/message/694439#694439)

```
<h:message id="#{cc.attrs.id}ID_tooltip" 
    for="#{inputID}"
    styleClass="inputfield_error inplace" 
    tooltip="true" 
    showDetail="true" 
    showSummary="true" />

<rich:tooltip id="#{inputID}_err_tt" target="#{cc.attrs.id}ID_tooltip" styleClass="tooltip" layout="block">
    <rich:message id="#{inputID}_msg_tt" for="#{inputID}" showDetail="true" showSummary="false" styleClass="inp_err_tt" />
</rich:tooltip>
```

The input component:

```
<h:inputText
    value="#{cc.attrs.managedBean.formField(cc.attrs.id).value}" 
    id="#{inputID}">
    <a4j:ajax event="change" execute="@this" render="#{cc.attrs.managedBean.actionForm.renderIds}"/>
</h:inputText>

<rich:tooltip target="#{cc.attrs.inputTxt}" id="#{tooltipID}" showDelay="300" styleClass="tooltip" layout="block">
    <h:outputText class="tt_val" value="#{cc.attrs.inputValue}" rendered="#{!bean.hasMessages(rich:clientId(cc.attrs.inputTxt))}"/>
    <rich:message id="#{inputID}_err_tt" 
            for="#{inputID}" showDetail="true" 
            showSummary="false" styleClass="inp_err_tt"
            rendered="#{cc.attrs.managedBean.hasMessages(rich:clientId(cc.attrs.inputTxt))}" />
</rich:tooltip>
```

result:

[image: result]

*(for the screenshot purpose i put the `tooltip="true"` in the h:message)*

It works perfect if i refrest the page... (when the input gets invalid).
It just doesnt work 'realtime'. Looks to me some kind of rerender issue.

Only the `<h:message id="#{cc.attrs.id}ID_tooltip" ... />` get rerendered 'realtime'. I also want the tooltips to rerender. How do i manage that?

Comment: Both of the tooltips? Note that the solution you've linked is for RF 3, some things might not work the same way.

Comment: My bad, in my code i changed the 'for' already to 'target' on the message tooltip. I guess u meant that. Updated the question. but yes, they both work.

Comment: Assuming the rerender ids are ok you can check the generated code, the tooltips will be there, just not visible - if they are not updated it's an issue with the rerender, if they are then it could be JavaScript.